# gmLib Polyline deleting single points by right click on a point

Tags: delphi, gmlib

in a delphi Maps Project with gmLib i try to create Polylines by clicking on the maps, this works well. Now I would like to delete single points of that polyline by showing a popup menu on right click onto a single point. 
The event GMPolylineRightClick is fired and I can show my popup this event return values for Lat, Lng and an Index however this index is the index of the polyline itself how can I get the point index?

Comment: You can just find the closest point from Polyline to the event